# Android Web App - web page run in background

Tags: android, background

I have an android app that displays a web page with a timer event. When the app gets backgrounded, does the javascript also stop. If I have a timer event in the javascript and the app gets backgrounded does the javascript stop running?

Can anyone suggest how to write an app so that if it gets backgrounded, the javascript timer event keeps going? Or do I have to write a service?

Answer (score 0):

A service would be your best bet because that is guaranteed to continue running in the background. The way Android apps work, there is a chance your web page will get "destroyed" and then brought back when you want it so you would lose your timer.

Check out the diagrams near the bottom of the page:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html

Comment: so should the service run the web view..do i still need an activity that runs a web view and the service wakes it up..should the app be just a service..

Comment: What's the overall purpose of the timer? What is it suppose to trigger?

Comment: ok i have a web page with a timer event that sends a update on a regular basis to a server mysql db via PHP and when the app activity goes to background the web page does actually keep sending updates! but what if it gets killed should a sevice restart it..

Comment: Only the 4 most recent activities remain active in the background (the last time I read up on activities) so it would still keep sending the updates. If you opened a bunch of other applications, or if you left the web page alone too long it would kill the process to free up the memory since the user isn't interacting with it.

A service would give you a more robust control over what you want to do.

Comment: yes you are right an web app activity does stay active in the background until it is killed by OS but this is not ideal. So should i start a service ...and it then launches and relaunches the activity?

Comment: Since it seems the timing of the updates is what you seemed concerned about, that would be the ideal way of doing it. Service in the background, activity that interfaces with it whenever you need to look at the status, make changes, etc.